# Run desktop app in the background

Tags: gnome, icons, launcher, .desktop

I have coded a small desktop utility for Ubuntu and I would like to run it in the "background".

For "background" I mean the app icon will appear in the top menu bar only and not when I switch tabs.

[image]

I have google around, but I did not find anything.
Does this comes from the framework I am using or from the Unity launcher? **Unfortunately I do not know the name of this**

This is my `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Warp
Comment=Warp Linux gui client for Cloudflare Warp.
Exec=/usr/local/bin/warp-gui
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/32/warp-gui.jpeg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/warp-cli;
StartupNotify=false
```

Comment: It is up to the programmer, i.e., you in this case, to enable the possibility for the app to "skip the taskbar" while minimizing, and eventually display a tray icon. You probably will have more luck with your question on a forum that is more specialized on programming.

Comment: What are your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you can use special application named [AllTray](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/alltray), its purpose is:

> Dock any program into the system tray

You can install it with

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alltray
```

and then configure it launch your application. See `man alltray` locally (or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/alltray.1.html)) for details.